# Can't use custom Comparator in Java

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I have problem with implementing my custom comparator for my class:

```
public class MyProject {
    private static class SuperClass {
        public SuperClass (ArrayList<Car> cars) {
            Collections.sort(cars);
            Collections.sort(cars, new Car.CustomOrder());
        }
    }

    public final static class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
        public Comparator<Car> customOrder() {
            return new CustomOrder();
        }

        public class CustomOrder implements Comparator<Car> {
            public int compare(Car c1, Car c2) {
                // some code
                return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to sort cars by custom comparator `CustomOrder`.
I can't find my mistake so please help me.

Comment: This code is full of uncompilable code. Have you read the error messages from the compiler? What do they say? What don't you understand? Why do you think it's a good idea to nest all your classes that way?

Comment: What is car... or more specific: what has car for fields that you can relate to a custom order??

Comment: Also, it makes no sense (to me at least) to call `sort()` in the ctor of the SuperClass.  This isn't required by the `Comparator` class, and it makes no sense to force a sort operation like this in a comparator.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to implement `public int compareTo(Car o)` in `Car` class to compile your program.
2. `Collections.sort(cars, new Car().new CustomOrder());`, because `CustomOrder` is an inner class, not a static nested one. It may be created by the existing reference to the outer class.

An instance of an inner class can exist only within an instance of an outer class and has direct access to the methods and fields of its enclosing instance.

---

It seems you don't understand inner and nested classes completely. I suggest reading about [them](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) on Oracle Tutorials.

Comment: While you're correct to say that a new CustomOrder can be created like this, I think you should also say it's probably terrible design for the OP to nest his classes this way.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew Tobilko suggested, you have to implement compareTo method in Car class because you want to compare Car objects.

Take a look at the link [Java Object Sorting](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

Also please, write clean code. Your code is hard to read even though it is short.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get rid off the static keyword, that is not a nice way to go and can become easily in a bad design pattern.

you have the class Car, and a list of those somewhere, so independently of if the car implements or not a comparable, you can use an anonymous one and use the fields you need for the sort criteria...

## Example:

sorting the list by **OrderId** (just an String)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Car> myCars = new ArrayList<>();
    myCars.add(new Car(0, "qqweqw", "qwe"));
    myCars.add(new Car(1, "Aqqweqw", "qwe"));
    myCars.add(new Car(2, "Zqqweqw", "qwe"));

    System.out.println("unsorted list" + myCars);
    Collections.sort(myCars, new Comparator<Car>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Car o1, Car o2) {
            return o1.getOrder().compareTo(o2.getOrder());
        }
    });
    System.out.println("sorted list" + myCars);

}
```

then as yo can see, no need to declare a new **comparator** class that binds dependencies to the Car class

Comment: I would rather write a lambda than the anonymous class